# Select shortlisted timezone list in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I know that this query return all the possible timezones in Oracle

```
select distinct tzname d, tzname r
from V$TIMEZONE_NAMES
order by 1
```

but that gives 597 rows which is difficult for the user to choose the favorite one.

Is there a way to select a shortlisted list like the one [here](https://jp.cybozu.help/general/en/admin/list_systemadmin/list_localization/timezone.html)

I'm using oracle 21c with Oracle APEX.

Comment: This is a common problem. A solution is to create your own time zone table based on V$TIMEZONE_NAMES and then remove the entries you don't want to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a distinct time zone for each location and then find a single time zone name for each time zone in each region:

```sql
SELECT region,
       tzname,
       tzabbrev
FROM   (
  SELECT region,
         tzname,
         tzabbrev,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY region, tzabbrev
           ORDER BY tzname
         ) AS region_tz_rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT SUBSTR(TZNAME, 1, INSTR(TZNAME, '/') - 1) AS region,
           TZNAME,
           TZABBREV,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY tzname
             ORDER BY
               -- Prefer named time zone over a UTC offset and, if possible, ignore LMT.
               CASE 
               WHEN TZABBREV = 'LMT' -- Local Mean Time
               THEN 2
               WHEN TZABBREV LIKE '-%' OR TZABBREV LIKE '+%'
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
               END,
               TZABBREV
           ) AS tz_rn
    FROM   V$TIMEZONE_NAMES
  )
  WHERE  tz_rn = 1
)
WHERE  region_tz_rn = 1;
```

Which filters from over 2000 original entries down to about 200 rows:

> | REGION | TZNAME | TZABBREV |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Africa | Africa/Casablanca | +00 |
> | Africa | Africa/Juba | CAST |
> | Africa | Africa/Blantyre | CAT |
> | Africa | Africa/Algiers | CEST |
> | Africa | Africa/Addis_Ababa | EAT |
> | Africa | Africa/Cairo | EEST |
> | Africa | Africa/Abidjan | GMT |
> | Africa | Africa/Johannesburg | SAST |
> | Africa | Africa/Ndjamena | WAST |
> | Africa | Africa/Bangui | WAT |
> | America | America/Scoresbysund | +00 |
> | America | America/Noronha | -01 |
> | America | America/Araguaina | -02 |
> | ... | ... | ... |
> | US | US/Alaska | AHDT |
> | US | US/Aleutian | AHST |
> | US | US/Central | CDT |
> | US | US/Michigan | CST |
> | US | US/Eastern | EDT |
> | US | US/Hawaii | HDT |
> | US | US/Arizona | MDT |
> | US | US/Pacific | PDT |
> | US | US/Samoa | SST |
> | *null* | Kwajalein | +09 |
> | *null* | NZ-CHAT | +1215 |
> | *null* | GB | BDST |
> | *null* | Eire | BST |
> | *null* | CST | CDT |
> | *null* | CET | CEST |
> | *null* | EST5EDT | EDT |
> | *null* | EET | EEST |
> | *null* | EST | EST |
> | *null* | GMT | GMT |
> | *null* | Hongkong | HKST |
> | *null* | HST | HST |
> | *null* | Israel | IDDT |
> | *null* | Japan | JDT |
> | *null* | ROK | JST |
> | *null* | MST7MDT | MDT |
> | *null* | MET | MEST |
> | *null* | MST | MST |
> | *null* | NZ | NZDT |
> | *null* | PST | PDT |
> | *null* | Singapore | SMT |
> | *null* | Iran | TMT |
> | *null* | UCT | UTC |
> | *null* | WET | WEST |

If you want to filter down even more then you can find equivalent time zones and aggregate them (i.e. `+00`, `UTC`, `GMT` are equivalent and could be combined).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d66229bd51576af6b0f14fabdf5ff874)*